# Which permission allows a user to create Task Groups in TFS 2017 Build?

Tags: tfs, permissions

When I try to create a task group from a task in my build definition in TFS 2017, I get an error that says

> Access denied.  (user name) needs Edit task group permissions to
>   perform the action.  For more information, contact the Team Foundation
>   Server administrator.

I've checked the following documentation pages, but none of them seem to mention how to grant `edit task group` permission:

- [Task Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/task-groups)
- [Permissions and groups in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions)
- [Build and release permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/permissions)

I'd like to know the correct way to grant this permission.

Additional information:
My account is a member of a `Builders` group in the appropriate project, and that Builders group has `Allow` set for every permission listed at the above Build and release permissions link, except `override check-in validation by build` and `Update build information` which are both `Not Set`, and the documentation recommends leaving those permissions as they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is good, except that I have no Builders group... perhaps due to the upgrade path that had been followed on that server.

Go to Task Groups hub, e.g. http://{server}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_apps/hub/ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.hub-metatask, and hover on `Task Groups` in left pane, click Ellipsis and choose Security.   By default, the old `Builders` group is not in there, but Build Administrators is.  The permission `Edit task group` can be set here, if needed, but it looks like the correct thing to do is add the user to one of the groups `Build Administrators`, `Project Administrators` or `Release Administrators`.

Answer (score 5):

There are three related permission  **Administer task group permissions**, **Delete task group**, **Edit task group** for task groups configuration.

You could set it from  Build&Release --Task Group--right click it in left pane--select **security**.

[image]

However just like some other permission settings, you could also  directly add a user or TFS group here. After add a user, there should be a **users**  list under TFS group list.

"*Build Administrators*", "*Contributors*","*Project Administrators*" or "*Release Administrators*" there are just four default groups here.  You don't have to add your user account in these groups and set the permission for a specific group to grant related permission of "task group". For example, if you don't want to give all users in a group the correspondingly permission, you could simply give the permission for a user.

In your case, you could add your old "Builders" group here or just add your owner account either directly here or one of a default group.